# UIImageView PNG pixelation on iOS simulator and on device

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

This may be a very simple issue, but I've been stuck with this for a week. I'm using an UIImageView to display a Dropbox branding PNG image. I see it alright in Interface Builder, but it's easy to notice a strong pixelation in the iOS Simulator and in the actual device (an iPad). Here I attach a screen capture of the IB together with the simulator:

[image: On the left the IB. On the right the simulator. Notice the pixelation.]

I would really appreciate any hint.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InterfaceBuilder is a completely different environment than iOS or even the simulator. Layout and such should translate, but the way everything looks should always be judged (and therefore designed for) the end product.

It looks like your image is being stretched slightly. There are any number of reasons for this. The first thing to check is the resizing mask on your UIImageView. It's generally bad for UIImageViews to autoresize - for this very reason.

By the way, autoresizing is UIKit's way of making sure that subviews still fit/look good when their parent view changes size. You can specify how much you want a subview to move around, also how much you want it to stretch. Read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW1).

What you will want to do is design your view -- answer the question: how big do I want this image to be in the final product? -- and then make the actual png that size (also produce an @2x variant that is double the size for retina displays). Then, when you design in IB, make your UIImageView that size as well, and make sure that the autoresizing settings are set to prohibit stretching.

This ought to fix your problem.

Comment: While you usually want to avoid resizing images, there are some situations where it makes sense do to device rotation or other changes. In these cases, iOS usually does a much better job than your screen shot. In other words, the sort of artifacts you're seeing usually only occurs in the extreme cases, such as or slightly or greatly scaling an image larger or smaller. Or, it could be that your image is a 8bit PNG rather than a 24 bit PNG.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure the size of the image matches the size of your UIImageView. If the image happens to be smaller than the target image view, it will stretch to fill it which could cause pixelation. Also, if you are running the new 5.1 Simulator for iPad, it will default to the new retina screen, which means you will need the @2x sized images to prevent pixelation there.